# Overloadin, Overriding, and Binding in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, binding, overloading

I have a question as to what the output of the following code will be and more importantly - why it would be like that?

```
class Animal {
    public void makePair(Animal a) {
        System.out.println("A pair of animals");
    }
}

class Shark extends Animal{
    public void makePair(Shark s) {
        System.out.println("A pair of sharks");
    }
}

class Duck extends Animal {
    public void makePair(Duck d) {
        System.out.println("A pair of ducks");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shark bruce = new Shark();
        Shark anchor = new Shark();
        Animal donald = new Duck();
        Duck daffy = new Duck();
        bruce.makePair(anchor);
        donald.makePair(daffy);
        anchor.makePair(daffy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code? If so, what did it output?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about polymorphism, you can give it a read at
[Polymorphism in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-java/)

In the current case the output would be

A pair of sharks

A pair of animals

A pair of animals

**Explanation**

These lines

```
Shark bruce = new Shark();
Shark anchor = new Shark();
Animal donald = new Duck();
Duck daffy = new Duck();
```

state that
bruce is a shark, anchor is a shark, donald is a duck and daffy is a duck.

Secondly the lines written below

```
class Shark extends Animal
class Duck extends Animal
```

states that both Shark and Duck are animals plus there is a method named makePair() in each class. Now let's move to the output that how it came that way

the first output line came from

```
bruce.makePair(anchor);
```

as we already know bruce and anchor are sharks and the method present in shark class is

```
public void makePair(Shark s) {
    System.out.println("A pair of sharks");
}
```

that shows it takes a Shark (same class object) as parameter so it came that way.

Now moving to the last line of output that is from

```
anchor.makePair(daffy);
```

as we know anchor is a shark and Daffy is a duck, now in this case the compiler checks that the method defined in Shark class accepts duck as parameter if no, it will check its parent class that is there a method that accepts duck as parameter. In this case the method defined in parent class

```
public void makePair(Animal a) {
    System.out.println("A pair of animals");
}
```

doesn't accept duck but accepts Animal and we know that both shark and duck are animals so this is printed. 
Now let's come to the most exciting one second line of output which is from

```
donald.makePair(daffy);
```

both are ducks but ouput is A pair of animals, because let's recall the donald object definition

```
Animal donald = new Duck();
```

here you can see reference of parent class and object of child class. Now whenever there is a case that object is defined in such a way and both parent and child have function with same name([Overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/)). The function that is executed is the function of reference class (which is parent (Animal) class) in this case that's why we got such output.

Comment: There are no overridden methods in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It outputs:

A pair of sharks

A pair of animals

A pair of animals

You are not overriding the `Animal` in the 2 classes that extend it so `Duck` and `Shark` will each have 2 versions and Java will "find" the correct method.

In your example:

`bruce.makePair(anchor);`

Prints "A pair of sharks" because both are `Shark`

`donald.makePair(daffy);`

Prints "A pair of animals" donald is a `Duck` but is declared an `Animal` so it only has access to the `Animal.makePair()` and daffy extends `Animal` so it is acceptable.

`anchor.makePair(daffy);`

Prints "A pair of animals" because anchor is a `Shark` and daffy a `Duck`, the only method signature that works is the `Animal` one.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler decides which method to call based on the information you have given it.

None of these methods override each other, since they each have a different *signature.*  The signature is comprised of the method name, the number of arguments, and the types of the arguments.

That makes this exercise easier, since the only thing that determines which method is going to be executed is what type the *compiler* thinks each object and argument are.

The compiler does not run methods or constructors.  It only knows what you tell it, when you declare a variable.

- You declared `Shark bruce` and `Shark anchor`, so the compiler knows that bruce and anchor are of type Shark.  Therefore, it chooses the most specific method of the Shark class:  the `makePair(Shark s)` method.
- You declared `Animal donald`, so the compiler only knows that donald is of type Animal.  It doesn’t matter what you actually assigned to it, because the compiler didn’t run that code.  What the compiler knows is what you told it, and that is that donald is of type Animal, and that type only has one method, so the `makePair(Animal a)` method is called.
- The compiler knows anchor is of type Shark, but daffy is of type Duck.  Shark declares its own makePair method which accepts an argument of type Shark, but the daffy argument does not match that, so the only method that can match is the `makePair(Animal a)` method which Shark inherits from Animal.